# How to extract and visualize values from a log entry in OpenShift EFK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, openshift, kibana, fluentd

I have an OKD cluster setup with EFK stack for logging, as described [here](https://docs.okd.io/3.11/install_config/aggregate_logging.html). I have never worked with one of the components before.

One deployment logs requests that contain a specific value that I'm interested in. I would like to extract just this value and visualize it with an area map in Kibana that shows the amount of requests and where they come from.

The content of the `message` field basically looks like this:

```
[fooServiceClient#doStuff] {"somekey":"somevalue", "multivalue-key": {"plz":"12345", "foo": "bar"}, "someotherkey":"someothervalue"}
```

This `plz` is a German zip code, which I would like to visualize as described.

My problem here is that I have no idea how to extract this value.

A nice first success would be if I could find it with a regexp, but Kibana doesn't seem to work the way I think it does. Following its docs, I expect this `/\"plz\":\"[0-9]{5}\"/` to deliver me the result, but I get 0 hits (time interval is set correctly). Even if this regexp matches, I would only find the log entry where this is contained and not just the specifc value. How do I go on here?

I guess I also need an external geocoding service, but at which point would I include it? Or does Kibana itself know how to map zip codes to geometries?

A beginner-friendly step-by-step guide would be perfect, but I could settle for some hints that guide me there.

Comment: As I understand it, your message field is a text field and not parsed JSON, right? In Kibana you can try the following free-text query and it should work: `plz\":\"/[0-9]{5}/`

Comment: This returns me any log entry that contains five consecutive digits. My message field looks like: `[fooServiceClient#getStuff] {"many-keys": "many-values"}`, so it's probably a text field.

Comment: Is there any way you can parse the `message` field upstream and store it as JSON hash instead of text? it would be much easier and less brittle to query your data by doing so.

Comment: I will look into this, but for my understanding: What would this change? I can't imagine that it's super complicated to extract a value from a text field. Maybe my idea of how to approach this is completely wrong?

Comment: Because you seem to be in need of structured search and not free-text search. Structured search works best when all the data is properly parsed and typed.

Comment: Have you been able to check whether you can parse the message field?

Comment: I don't have the option to parse the message field, it will stay in its shape no matter what. The idea seemed much easier than it turned out to be. :) Probably I would have to customize the ES to check every message field for the `plz` and create a new field from this, but 1. I have no idea of ES what so ever, 2. this would probably slow down things very badly.

Comment: It would still be possible to parse the message field as the document gets indexed into ES, using an [ingest pipeline with grok processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/grok-processor.html). Do you only need the `plz` value?

Comment: Yes, all I need is this value to visualize it on an area map. How to do the latter is also part of my question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to parse the `message` field as the document gets indexed into ES, using an [ingest pipeline with grok processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/grok-processor.html).

First, create the ingest pipeline like this:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/parse-plz
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "grok": {
        "field": "message",
        "patterns": [
          "%{POSINT:plz}"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, when you index your data, you simply reference that pipeline:

```
PUT plz/_doc/1?pipeline=parse-plz
{
  "message": """[fooServiceClient#doStuff] {"somekey":"somevalue", "multivalue-key": {"plz":"12345", "foo": "bar"}, "someotherkey":"someothervalue"}"""
}
```

And you will end up with a document like the one below, which now has a field called `plz` with the `12345` value in it:

```
{
  "message": """[fooServiceClient#doStuff] {"somekey":"somevalue", "multivalue-key": {"plz":"12345", "foo": "bar"}, "someotherkey":"someothervalue"}""",
  "plz": "12345"
}
```

When indexing your document from Fluentd, you can [specify a pipeline to be used](https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch#pipeline) in the configuration. If you can't or don't want to modify your Fluentd configuration, you can also define a default pipeline for your index that will kick in every time a new document is indexed. Simply run this on your index and you won't need to specify `?pipeline=parse-plz` when indexing documents:

```
PUT index/_settings
{
  "index.default_pipeline": "parse-plz"
}
```

If you have several indexes, a better approach might be to define an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) instead, so that whenever a new index called `project.foo`-something is created, the settings are going to be applied:

```
PUT _template/project-indexes
{
  "index_patterns": ["project.foo*"],
  "settings": {
     "index.default_pipeline": "parse-plz"
  }
}
```

Now, in order to map that PLZ on a map, you'll first need to find a data set that provides you with geolocations for each PLZ.

You can then add a second processor in your pipeline in order to do the PLZ/ZIP to lat,lon mapping:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/parse-plz
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "grok": {
        "field": "message",
        "patterns": [
          "%{POSINT:plz}"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "ctx.location = params[ctx.plz];",
        "params": {
          "12345": {"lat": 42.36, "lon": 7.33}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Ultimately, your document will look like this and you'll be able to leverage the `location` field in a Kibana visualization:

```
{
  "message": """[fooServiceClient#doStuff] {"somekey":"somevalue", "multivalue-key": {"plz":"12345", "foo": "bar"}, "someotherkey":"someothervalue"}""",
  "plz": "12345",
  "location": {
    "lat": 42.36, 
    "lon": 7.33
  }
}
```

So to sum it all up, it all boils down to only two things:

1. Create an ingest pipeline to parse documents as they get indexed
2. Create an index template for all `project*` indexes whose settings include the pipeline created in step 1

Comment: Thank you very much! I have successfully created the ingest pipeline (at least ES answers with `"acknowledged":true`), but I'm not sure what you mean by the next steps. "When I index my data" - when exactly does this happen and how can I reference a pipeline when it does? I don't see how calling the pipeline with an example message field helps me automating this step for each log entry that comes in. Also, in the second processor step: Why should I put a discrete value for plz in the pipeline?

Comment: The PUT request are just meant as examples on how to index data. How do you initially create your index? See my updated answer regarding how to specify the pipeline when indexing document from Fluentd.

Comment: The indexes are created automatically for each project when deploying the EFK stack to the OpenShift cluster. I have several indexes for one project that are always aggregated in Kibana, like `project.foo.abc123-456.*`. The `*` represents a date. I can't seem to easily reference all indexes for a project via one PUT request, can I (without writing a shell script)?

Comment: Index templates to the rescue! See my updated answer.

Comment: That sounds reasonable :) However, I get an error: ```{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: template is missing;"}],"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: template is missing;"},"status":400}``` - do you have an idea about this?

Comment: Actually you get that when running `PUT _template/project-indexes`. Try replacing `"index_patterns": ["project.foo*"],` by `"template": "project.foo*"` instead. Your ES version my differ from mine.

Comment: Yes you're right about when it happens, this was a typo, sorry! After replacing it, I get a new error: ```{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.default_pipeline] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown setting [index.default_pipeline] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"},"status":400}```

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: I'm on version 5.6.13. I didn't realize it was such an old version, sorry.

Comment: Oh, the `index.default_pipeline` setting was introduced in 6.5... So either you upgrade your ES or you'll need to modify the Fluentd configuration as I described.

Comment: Ok, both options will take me some more time. But I'm sure I'll get there, having your detailed instructions. :) Thanks for helping me out

Comment: Awesome, always glad to help!